# OS X - Big Sur - snap window to right/left

Tags: macos

After the recent upgrade (a few days ago) to Big Sur 14.3, I lost the functionality of dragging an app window to the left or right edge of the screen that would resize the window to take exactly half of the screen and snap to the left or right respectively. I don't recollect having any separate app for it - was it a setting in the system or I did indeed have some app adding this functionality? I've gone through a few system updates and it always remained there. It was after this recent update that the functionality disappeared. Nothing happens if I drag a window to the right edge (well if I hold it for two long near the right edge, the window gets dragged to the next Desktop, which is what it always did).

Thank you

Comment: I've never had the ability to window snap, without a third-party application. To tile the window left or right, just hover your mouse over the green maximize window button and it will present you with three options. Full screen, tile window left and tile window right. This does put the windows in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've gone through all the installed apps and found the one that was responsible for it - it was 'Rectangle'